# What is the user case for "kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateUIDToDevice"

Tags: macos, core-audio

According to

```
AudioHardware.h
```

kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateUIDToDevice

This property fetches the AudioObjectID that corresponds to the AudioDevice that has the given UID. The UID is passed in via the qualifier as a CFString while the AudioObjectID for the AudioDevice is returned to the caller as the property's data. Note that an error is not returned if the UID doesn't refer to any AudioDevices. Rather, this property will return kAudioObjectUnknown as the value of the property.

I wonder what is the user case for this property?

actually I also have question about

kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInList

kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateBundleIDToPlugIn
I wonder if where we could find more detailed reference about these properties?

Answer (score 4):

This is for when you need to store, such as in preferences, which device is used or selected for a particular purpose and then find that device on some subsequent run. It is the complement to:

```
@constant       kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID
                    A CFString that contains a persistent identifier for the AudioDevice. An
                    AudioDevice's UID is persistent across boots. The content of the UID string
                    is a black box and may contain information that is unique to a particular
                    instance of an AudioDevice's hardware or unique to the CPU. Therefore they
                    are not suitable for passing between CPUs or for identifying similar models
                    of hardware. The caller is responsible for releasing the returned CFObject.
```

So, you would fetch the device's UID and store that in your preferences or document. Then, on a subsequent run or when that document is opened, you can use `kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateUIDToDevice` to look up the `AudioDevice` object from that UID.

Comment: thanks for your explaining. I wonder if I could have an example please?